# angular directive for post DOM load

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm sort of a beginner to angular and needing help constructing a directive for post DOM load. 
I have this script below functional, but it uses a timer. I'd rather have something more robust insuring post DOM load timing than a timer.
From the info I found on stackoverflow and angular docs, a directive seems like a way to go to run a script after Dom is done loading.

I have attempted creating a directive (also attaching here), but the values I'm attempting to pass into my directive are not reachable for some reason.

Here is what does work in my controller, but relies on the timer:

```
app.controller('EditCropCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $log, $location, $injector, $timeout) {     
    var service = $injector.get('copyImageMasterURLService');
    $scope.masterUrl = service.getMasterUrl();
    $scope.crop = service.getCrop();

    // image editor library
    var pos = new Position();
    pos.top = $scope.crop.top;
    pos.left =$scope.crop.left;
    pos.width = $scope.crop.width;
    pos.height = $scope.crop.height;

    $timeout(function () { //need this timeout to be sure its run after DOM render.
        var maxWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
        var maxHeight = window.innerHeight;
        var imcw = pos ? pos.width : maxWidth
        var imch = pos ? pos.height : maxHeight;
        var rw = maxWidth/imcw;
        var rh = maxHeight/imch;

        window.imageEditorZoom = rw < rh ? rw : rh;
        window.imageEditor = new ImageEditor("cropMaster");
        editor.disableScaling();
        editor.setCropping(pos);
        editor.zoom(window.imageEditorZoom);

    }, 1000, false);
});
```

Here is also my attempt at creative a directive for the above, but both croptool, posX return null:

```
app.controller('EditCropCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $log, $location, $injector, $timeout) {     
    var service = $injector.get('copyImageMasterURLService');
    $scope.masterUrl = service.getMasterUrl();
    $scope.crop = service.getCrop();

    // construct image editor
    var pos = new Position();
    pos.top = $scope.crop.top;
    pos.left =$scope.crop.left;
    pos.width = $scope.crop.width;
    pos.height = $scope.crop.height;

    $scope.croptool = {
        posX: pos
    }; 
});
app.directive('myCroptool', function($timeout) {
    var crop = null;
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        $timeout(function () { // You might need this timeout to be sure its run after DOM render.
            console.log("...0 here we are... ", croptool, posX);

        }, 0, false);
    }
    return {
      link: link
    };
});
```

I would really love to figure this out. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to use the $postLink lifecycle hook in the controller

```
app.controller('EditCropCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $log, $location, $document, $injector, $window) {     
    var service = $injector.get('copyImageMasterURLService');
    $scope.masterUrl = service.getMasterUrl();
    $scope.crop = service.getCrop();

    // image editor library
    var pos = new Position();
    pos.top = $scope.crop.top;
    pos.left =$scope.crop.left;
    pos.width = $scope.crop.width;
    pos.height = $scope.crop.height;

    this.$postLink = function () { 
        var maxWidth = $document.body.clientWidth;
        var maxHeight = $window.innerHeight;
        var imcw = pos ? pos.width : maxWidth
        var imch = pos ? pos.height : maxHeight;
        var rw = maxWidth/imcw;
        var rh = maxHeight/imch;

        $window.imageEditorZoom = rw < rh ? rw : rh;
        $window.imageEditor = new ImageEditor("cropMaster");
        editor.disableScaling();
        editor.setCropping(pos);
        editor.zoom($window.imageEditorZoom);

    };
});
```

Comment: I'm trying this out, but it is not doing anything. I even added a log.info message. It seems the script inside this.$postLink function  is not executing at all. Do I need to install a separate angular plug in for it?

Comment: What version of angular are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 1.5.8.